Code -32000 ("processing response error") when reading data from a polygon smart contract
I am just starting out with ethers.js and smart contracts in general. I am attempting to read the price between two tokens (MATIC => WETH) using the getAmountsOut() function on the sushiswap router (0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506). My code is below.
const ethers = require('ethers');
const {
    addressSushiFactory,
    addressSushiRouter, 
    addressOneinchFactory,
    addressOneinchRouter,
    addressFrom,
    addressTo
} = require('./addressList');
const {
    decimalsABI,
    sushiGetAmountsOutABI
} = require('./abiList');

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/###########");
const contractRouter = new ethers.Contract(addressSushiRouter, sushiGetAmountsOutABI, provider);

const GetPrices = async (humanIn) => {
    const contractDecimalsFrom = new ethers.Contract(addressFrom, decimalsABI, provider);
    const decimalsFrom = await contractDecimalsFrom.decimals();
    const bigIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits(humanIn, decimalsFrom).toString();

    const amountsOut = await contractRouter.getAmountsOut(bigIn, [addressFrom, addressTo]);
    console.log(bigOut);
}

GetPrices("1000");

However, when I run it I receive the error:
var error = new Error(message);
                    ^

Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":46,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"execution reverted\"}}","error":{"code":-32000},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_call\",\"params\":[{\"to\":\"0x1b02da8cb0d097eb8d57a175b88c7d8b47997506\",\"data\":\"0xd06ca61f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a76400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010100000000000000000000000007ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619\"},\"latest\"],\"id\":46,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/1c907e346a334bd9b230b2ab851aaca0"}, data="0x", code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.6.5)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:233:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:242:20)
    at checkError (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:103:16)
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:687:47)
    at step (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string',
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  error: Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":46,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"execution reverted\"}}", error={"code":-32000}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_call\",\"params\":[{\"to\":\"0x1b02da8cb0d097eb8d57a175b88c7d8b47997506\",\"data\":\"0xd06ca61f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a76400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010100000000000000000000000007ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619\"},\"latest\"],\"id\":46,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/1c907e346a334bd9b230b2ab851aaca0", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.6.0)
      at Logger.makeError (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:233:21)
      at Logger.throwError (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:242:20)
      at /Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:305:32
      at step (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
      at Object.next (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
      at fulfilled (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    reason: 'processing response error',
    code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
    body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":46,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"}}',
    error: Error: execution reverted
        at getResult (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:170:21)
        at processJsonFunc (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:348:22)
        at /Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:280:46
        at step (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
        at Object.next (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
        at fulfilled (/Users/callumfrederiksen/Documents/arbitrage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      code: -32000,
      data: undefined
    },
    requestBody: '{"method":"eth_call","params":[{"to":"0x1b02da8cb0d097eb8d57a175b88c7d8b47997506","data":"0xd06ca61f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a76400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010100000000000000000000000007ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619"},"latest"],"id":46,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
    requestMethod: 'POST',
    url: 'https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/1c907e346a334bd9b230b2ab851aaca0'
  },
  data: '0x'
}

Node.js v22.4.0

Could someone please help me with this?
I have attached my code and the error but I cannot find anything else online
